# Merge Two Columns Values Into One and Create Another One With Their Names as Rows Value in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following table as pandas `DataFrame`:

```py
In [1]: a
Out[1]:
  name  X  Y
0    a  1  2
1    b  2  3
2    c  3  4
```

I'd like to know an efficient way i.e. without creating a new `DataFrame`, to "merge" column X and Y into a single column, and then turn their names into values of a new column, e.g.:

```py
In [1]: a
Out[1]:
  name  Col Z
0    a  X   1
1    a  Y   2
1    b  X   2
1    b  Y   3
2    c  X   3
2    c  Y   4
```

Could you help me?

Comment: `df.melt('name')` or `df.set_index('name').stack().reset_index(name='Z')`.

Comment: `melt` was the method I was looking for! I didn't realize unpivot was the term as well. Thanks!